# Help: List contents of iPhone application bundle subpath?

Tags: iphone

I am trying to get a listing of the directories contained within a subpath of my application bundle.  I've done some searching and this is what I have come up with

```
- (void) contents {
 NSArray *contents = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathsForResourcesOfType:nil
                                               inDirectory:@"DataDir"];
 if (contents = nil) {
  NSLog(@"Failed: path doesn't exist or error!");
 } else {
     NSString *bundlePathName = [[NSBundle mainBundle] bundlePath];
  NSString *dataPathName = [bundlePathName stringByAppendingPathComponent:
                                 @"DataDir"];
     NSFileManager *fileManager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];

     NSMutableArray *directories = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
     for (NSString *entityName in contents) {
            NSString *fullEntityName = [dataPathName
                                       stringByAppendingPathComponent:entityName];
            NSLog(@"entity = %@", fullEntityName);
            BOOL isDir = NO;
            [fileManager fileExistsAtPath:fullEntityName isDirectory:(&isDir)];
            if (isDir) {
                [directories addObject:fullEntityName];
                NSLog(@" is a directory");
            } else {
                NSLog(@" is not a directory");
            }
        }
        NSLog(@"Directories = %@", directories);

        [directories release];
 }
}
```

As you can see I am trying to get a listing of directories in the app bundle's DataDir subpath.  The problem is that I get no strings in my contents NSArray.

note:
- I am using the simulator
- When I manually look in the .app file I can see DataDir and the contents therein
- The contents of DataDir are png files and directories that contain png files
- The application logic needs to discover the contents of DataDir at runtime
- I have also tried using

```
 NSArray *contents = [fileManager contentsOfDirectoryAtPath:DataDirPathName error:nil];
```

and I still get no entries in my contents array

Any suggestions/alternative approaches?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure what I was doing wrong yesterday but I have this code working:

```
NSString *bundlePathName = [[NSBundle mainBundle] bundlePath];
NSString *dataPathName = [bundlePathName stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"DataDir"];
NSFileManager *fileManager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
    if ([fileManager fileExistsAtPath:dataPathName]) {
        NSLog(@"%@ exists", dataPathName);
        BOOL isDir = NO;
        [fileManager fileExistsAtPath:dataPathName isDirectory:(&isDir)];
        if (isDir == YES) {
            NSLog(@"%@ is a directory", dataPathName);
            NSArray *contents;
            contents = [fileManager contentsOfDirectoryAtPath:dataPathName error:nil];
            for (NSString *entity in contents) {
                NSLog(@"%@ is within", entity);
            }
        } else {
            NSLog(@"%@ is not a directory", dataPathName);
        }
    } else {
        NSLog(@"%@ does not exist", dataPathName);
    }
```